# Encoding an email to UTF8

Tags: c#, .net

I currently generate emails "on the fly" and was wondering whether I should be converting the body output to UTF-8 rather than original ASCII?

Comment: Just make sure you are properly marking your content as ASCII, and not just letting clients assume it.

Also, the mail stuff in the .NET 4 (and 3.5) BCL is very sophisticated and easy to use; you should try it instead of generating "on the fly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the content of the emails is ASCII, there is no reason to convert to UTF-8.

Convert to UTF-8 if you need to support multiple languages in your email.

Comment: Is that the only reason that I should convert the text?

Comment: @Ardman Yes, if you know you'll never need anything beyond ASCII, you can stick to ASCII. It won't make a difference to people reading your mail. In fact, I daresay support for ASCII in the wild far exceeds support for UTF-8, sadly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients#Features